# Auto Populate ADF Form from ADF Table

Tags: user-interface, jsf, oracle-adf

I have an ADF table which has to populate a form after redirecting to a new page.
Basically I have to implement the Edit functionality for a record selected in the table.
I have made the following iterator bindings to the fields but am not sure of how the values will be fetched from the database. I am unable to debug the bindings as the page does not render when redirected to.

Here is a snippet of the pageDef created

```
<attributeValues id="sedol" IterBinding="findD1ByCaIdIter">
  <AttrNames>
    <Item Value="sedol"/>
  </AttrNames>
</attributeValues>
```

Any help/tutorial/guide would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using a data control. If so, then use the data control to populate the table. Make sure to turn on single row selection.
Then on the Edit page, add the same data control as a form. ADF's built-in row concurrency will set the selected table row to be the "current row" in the iterator and bound VO Rowset. Then, when the Edit page is displayed, it will retrieve the "current row" from the iterator and it should be the selected row from the table.

Since you seem to be new to ADF, I suggest you learn a bit more, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/jdeveloper-reviewrguide-086026.html), [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html) and you can try to google "oracle adf table and form edit" -> some ideas [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1059826?db=5), [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/103-tabletoformdragdrop-1833210.pdf), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e16272/databound_table.htm#ADFJE154).

Basic info like what is your data source (ADF BC or JPA) and are you familiar with ADF Data Controls and what version of ADF are you using are very helpful with questions like these.

Comment: does it make any difference if your data source is ADF BC or JPA ?

Comment: Not from the perspective of using a data control. While you won't have VOs and rowsets, you'll have a data control based on a session bean base don an JPA entity, but the row concurrency will work the same. Which is the exact point of using a data control. read more here https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFDC/adfm.htm#ADFDC766  Also, remember to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in table in the end. drop on button (`ADFfaces`) and in its actionlistener add the following code:

```
public void editData() {
    DCBindingContainer contxt = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry(); 
    DCIteratorBinding iter =  contxt.findIteratorBinding("TestView1Iterator");           
    ViewObject testVo = iter.getViewObject();
    Row selectedRow = testVo.getCurrentRow();
}
```